# Android Studio 1.4: Unable to set correct config path

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

When I start android studio 1.4, it pops:

> Config path 'S:/.AndroidStudio1.4/config' is invalid.
>   If you have modified the 'idea.config.path' property please make sure it is correct,
>   otherwise please re-install the IDE.

It seems android studio wants to use S:. Once I insert my SD card as S:\, android studio will create .AndroidStudio1.4 on it and run correctly. If I eject my SD card, it just go back to error.

I failed to correct this "config path" to `%HOME%\.AndroidStudio1.4\config` which is usually used. I've tried to set `idea.config.path` both in

`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\idea.properties`

and

`%HOME%\.AndroidStudio1.4\idea.properties` (according to http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration) but it still ask me for S:\ drive.

I've also reinstalled android studio and restart for several times. It has confused me that where does android studio 1.4 actually load the config path variable? How does it log S:\ as the home directory?

PS. I've checked both user and system environment variables and there is nothing include S:. Nothing found in registry, either.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that due to this bug http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4787931 , java set %UserProfile% to the parent folder of Desktop folder instead of directly reading from environment. Thus Android Studio get the wrong %UserProfile% path.

To solve this problem, set a environment variable "-Djava.home" whose value is the real path of your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hey everyone,
If you guys are having the issue above, what that means is that basically the application cannot be run as administrator. You can test it using following steps:

1. type in terminal cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS

- this command changes directories to the contents of the Android Studio app you see in applications folder (you pretty much can't access it any other way)

2. then run sudo ./studio

- this command essentially runs the Android Studio app with root access

This should open up the Android Studio app for you with ROOT being displayed. Like so:[image]

If you are getting this, it means the application installed correctly (if not, you may have to reinstall the application and repeat the process).
You'll notice that if you go back terminal and hit ctrl + c it will exit out the program and you will go back to the original error message if you try to open the application from applications folder.

To avoid having to run sudo every time you open the application, go back to terminal and in the same directory /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS
type in  sudo chown <your_user> . (swap <your_user> for your home directory name. it can be found if you run cd /Users ) this changes ownership of the directory from root to <your_user>.
Then run sudo chmod u+s . while in the same directory (this allows everything in the directory inherit the ownership of the directory).
And Voila! Should be working when you try running the app from applications folder.

### Hope this helped.

P.S: If you get an issue ending in port.lock you have to follow the directory specified to get to the port.lock file then delete it and run the application again.